# How can I declare a data-attribute using ERB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the HTML I am trying to replicate:

```
<div id="links">
    <a href="images/banana.jpg" title="Banana" data-gallery>
        <img src="images/thumbnails/banana.jpg" alt="Banana">
    </a>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how to do the `data-gallery` bit. How would I write such a thing with ERB?

Here's what I have so far:

```
<div id="links">
    <% for photo in @photos %>
      <%= link_to (image_tag photo.image.url(:medium))%>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="links">
    <% @photos.each do |photo| %>
      <%= link_to (image_tag photo.image.url(:medium)), 'data-gallery' => true%>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Notice the more Rubyish way of iterating through an array of objects with `each`.

Comment: I thinkg `data: { gallery: true }` is a little bit cleaner way how to do it. Both of these ways generates code `<a href="images/banana.jpg" data-gallery="true">`. If you want to do it withou value, you should do it like this `data: { gallery: '' }`

Comment: Yes, that's another way of doing it, but I chose the simplest for OP.

Answer (score -1):

Add `"data_gallery" => "value"` to your `link_to` in HTML block.